# Why is \exp_after:wN named \exp_after:wN?

Tags: expl3, naming

This may be a strange question, but it somehow bothers me.

In expl3 we find a command named `\exp_after:wN` which is an alias for TeX's `\expandafter`. According to the expl3 naming scheme, anything that comes after the colon is the signature of the command.

In this case we have `wN`. where `N` stands for an ordinary, single token and `w` for “weird”/unusual arguments, e.g. delimited arguments. Following that signature, the parameters of `\exp_after:wN` should be “something weird” followed by a single token.

However, `\expandafter`'s parameters seem to be the exact opposite of that, i.e. the first parameter has to be a single token after which “something” follows that possibly triggers a long series of absorbing tokens.

Why isn't `\exp_after:wN` called `\exp_after:Nw` then?

Comment: Because `\expandafter` skips one token and expand the one after that, e.g. in `\expandafter{\zz}`.  As you can see that next token can also be `{`, i.e. the first argument is not `N`-type.  In principle it should actually be `\exp_after:w` but it is too ubiquitous to change it now.

Comment: @HenriMenke That's all spot-on: could you make it into an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright I won't be on my computer before Sunday.  Better you write an answer in the meantime.

Comment: @HenriMenke OK, I've posted something slightly more detailed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\expandafter` primitive skips over one token *even if* it is category code 1 or 2 (so `{`/`}` typically). In `expl3` terms, an `N`-type argument is one that is a single token and can be grabbed without any special tricks: if you do

```
\cs_set_protected:Npn \foo:N #1 { \cs_show:N #1 }
```

you will *not* get the right outcome for `\foo:N { \baz }` (it will show `\baz` not `{`). As such, the first argument to `\exp_after:wN` is 'weird': it may be an `N`-type argument, `{` or `}` (with a bit of trickery it can also be a space).

Originally, the team had renamed `\expandafter` as `\exp_after:NN`, but as we tightened up the naming we realised that the first argument was not strictly `N`-type so adjusted to `w`. Later, we've concluded that once you have a `w`-type argument, it's not really desirable to have further arguments shown in the signature: `w` means 'weird, so the documentation'. However, we only concluded that *after* `\exp_after:wN` became well-established. On balance, for a case like this we are preferring stability, so will no rename further (to `\exp_after:w`).

---

By the way, it'w worth noting that the *second* argument to `\exp_after:wN` really does have to be `N`-type. The idea is to expand a token, which means that the second argument must be expandable. That means it's either a macro or an active char: these are both `N`-type as they can be grabbed 'normally'.

Comment: The second argument to `\exp_after:wN` *ought to be* `N`-type: one can write `\exp_after:wN {{` and TeX will dutifully do nothing, apart from removing the `\exp_after:wN` token.

Comment: @egreg Sure: I mean that this is the documented and supported behaviour. We have the same with _e.g._ `\exp_not:n`: you _can_ mess about but it's not supported.